# How can I log requests for unknown URL endpoints in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logging, servlet-filters

I have a Spring Boot application which uses `SpringBootServletInitializer`.
In my `Controller` I have multiple endpoints that are differentiated based on the param that are included in the URL, like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "myEndpoint", method = RequestMethod.GET, params = { "Id", "name", "petType" })
public void get(@RequestParam String id, @RequestParam String name,  @RequestParam String petType){
   //do stuff
} 

@RequestMapping(value = "myEndpoint", method = RequestMethod.GET, params = { "Id", "name"})
public void get(@RequestParam String id, @RequestParam String name){
   //do stuff
}
```

Having the params in the `@RequestMapping` tag means that if there are params missing then a response is sent back to the client that made the request telling them of their error; however, nothing is logged on the server side.
I want to implement logging, so if a request is made to `/myEndpoint` that is missing parameters then it shows up in the server logs. 
Something like the url and params of the original request. 
To that end I came across [this spring tutorial](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-http-logging), which I tried to implement. However I hit a problem whereby the tutorial implements a `CustomWebAppInitializer` that extends `WebApplicationInitalizer`, my app already extends `SpringBootServletInitializer`.
When I try implement both I get an error as SpringBoot has already the context root has already been initialized by the `SpringBootServletInitializer`.
When I try to override the `onStartup()` method in the `SpringBootServletInitializer` instead it appears to work, but then my application isn't initialized properly and cannot be accessed from the browser.

I tried overriding the the method and adding a filter before calling super and passing the `ServletContext` back up the chain, but that doesn't work either.

```
servletContext.addFilter("CommonsRequestLoggingFilter",
            CommonsRequestLoggingFilter.class)
    .addMappingForServletNames(null, false, "myApp");
    super.onStartup(servletContext);
```

I'm a bit lost. What am I doing wrong here? (probably everything).

Comment: Can't you use the logger filter and save every request whether it is 200 or 400, must be saved in database and from there you can retrieve it.

Comment: Well that's my problem, I don't know. Where should I look for that information?

Comment: please check if this can help 
https://gist.github.com/rgiaviti/80d50041541475d5ad7a752b53aa4eed

Answer (score 0):

Because Spring Boot already sets up the context, you don't need to use a CustomWebAppInitializer. You only need to declare a bean for CommonsRequestLoggingFilter in a Configuration class. If the behavior does not satisfy your needs, you can implement [javax.servlet.Filter](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html%20) and declare a bean for your implementation.

Comment: Hmmm... Yes, I tried that earlier today following this tutorial: https://www.javadevjournal.com/spring/log-incoming-requests-spring/ but I don't get any messages in any of my log files.

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint in the Filter to verify that your method is being called? Is your bean created? Could it be a logging configuration issue?

Comment: Just tried that now, the bean is being created. Could be a logging configuration issue. It's a spring boot app running in a wildfly instance, the build in tomcat is excluded from the package.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding Custom HandlerInterceptor on your WebMvcConfigurer for logging purpose.

```
@Configuration
public class HttpRequestInterceptorConfigurer implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    private static Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(HttpRequestInterceptorConfigurer.class);

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new HandlerInterceptor() {

            @Override
            public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
                LOG.info("URI : " +request.getRequestURI() +" - QueryStr : " +request.getQueryString());
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex) throws Exception {              
            }

        });

    }

}
```